# Question with setting variables in if statements

Tags: php

Here is the sample:

```
if(($test = array('key'=>true)) && $test['key']){
    // works
}
if($test = array('key'=>true) && $test['key']){
    // does not work
}
```

Why is the parenthesis required? My understanding is that it computes the first conditional then the second no matter what.

And is it "safe" to do an assignment like this?

Comment: There is a reason why many *modern* language ban this construct and/or have the appropriate static-typing to mitigate where it can bite. In C one used to write like Yoda to catch errors: `if (1 = x) {` -- more modern compilers warn if there is no outside `()` to show in the intent is to be an assignment (it doesn't change the allowed grammar). With the *possible* exception of the *idiomatic* while-readline (which is actually mostly broken in PHP), I see no reason to use this bug-prone syntax. Using multiple statements would make the intent more clear and show "it's what I wanted to do".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a matter of [operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) in the language.  In your second statement, you're essentially writing this to be evaluated:

```
$test = array('key'=>true) && $test['key'];
```

Just about any language is going to take that to mean this:

```
$test = (array('key'=>true) && $test['key']);
```

It's assigning to `$test` the value of the evaluation of the logical `&&` between the two other values.  So `$test` will be either `true` or `false` when evaluated.

Comment: AH! I didn't even think about that. Duh. Thanks. I was thinking it did `$test = array()` THEN `$test['key']`.

Comment: @Jason: Little oversights like that very early in my development career have led me to be parenthesis-crazy and as explicit as possible about my order of operations.  Sometimes my statements look a little like Lisp code, but there's no doubt as to what they're doing :)

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to use, but in this case the parenthesis are required for disambiguation. The [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) rules of PHP mean that the second line will be executed as:

```
if ($test = (array('key' => true) && $test['key'])) { .. }
```

So test will not be an array but a bool.

The practice of doing assignment in if statements itself is not really encouraging readability though, so you probably want to avoid doing this too much.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think the parens are required in PHP. they are in JS.

depends what you mean by "safe". it works. but some would argue that this is bad style and makes for less understandable and less maintainable code. otoh, K&R positively recommended it. it doesn't worry me and sometimes makes for tidier code.

Comment: The parenthesis are required. Test it.

Comment: The parenthesis are only required when run separately.  If you run them one after the other, like you show in your example, then the second one will evaluate to true as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's forcing the interpreter to perform the assignment before it attempts to evaluate any of conditions within the if.

Without the parenthesis, you're simply assigning the results of `array('key'=>true) && $test['key']` to $test.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, the assignment operator `=` has lower precedence that most other operators. (For more information, see the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)). Furthermore, the result of an expression using the assignment operator is the value of the assignment. With this in mind, consider the expressions you posted:

First example:
`($test = array('key'=>true)) && $test['key']`
The first part of this expression, `($test = array('key'=>true))` evaluates to `array('key'=>true)` (by the rule above), and the second part evaluates to `true` since the key was just set. Thus the whole expression evaluates to `true`.

Second example:
`$test = array('key'=>true) && $test['key']` By the rules of operator precedence, `$test` is going to get assigned the value of the expression `array('key'=>true) && $test['key']`. The first half of this is true, but `$test['key']` hasn't been set yet, so `true && false` is false, so `$test` takes the value `false`, which is also the result of the if condition.